# How can i implement a picture in my Java Frame

Tags: java

I dont know how to implement a picture into my frame.

I dont use layout manager instead i use absolute positioning.

I got this code from the internet so i dont really understand ever part 
but iam still learning it.

Maybe some of you guys can help me. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Insects;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class sssaa {

    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {

    pane.setLayout(null);

    // Buttons

    JButton Burger = new JButton("Burger");
    Burger.setFocusPainted(false);
    JButton Beilagen = new JButton("Beilagen");
    Beilagen.setFocusPainted(false);
    JButton Salate = new JButton("Salate");
    Salate.setFocusPainted(false);
    JButton Specials = new JButton("Specials");
    Specials.setFocusPainted(false);
    JButton Tagesgericht = new JButton("Tagesgericht");
    Tagesgericht.setFocusPainted(false);
    JButton Aktionsangebot = new JButton("Aktionsangebot");
    Aktionsangebot.setFocusPainted(false);
    JButton Getränke = new JButton("Getränke");
    Getränke.setFocusPainted(false);



    pane.add(Burger);
    pane.add(Beilagen);
    pane.add(Salate);
    pane.add(Specials);
    pane.add(Tagesgericht);
    pane.add(Aktionsangebot);
    pane.add(Getränke);

    //absolute positioning

    Insets insets = pane.getInsets();
    Dimension size = Burger.getPreferredSize();
    Burger.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 50 + insets.top,
                 size.width + 100, size.height + 50);
    size = Beilagen.getPreferredSize();
    Beilagen.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 130 + insets.top,
                 size.width + 90, size.height + 50);
    size = Salate.getPreferredSize();
    Salate.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 210 + insets.top,
                 size.width + 103, size.height + 50);
    size = Burger.getPreferredSize();
    Specials.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 290 + insets.top,
                 size.width + 100, size.height + 50);
    size = Beilagen.getPreferredSize();
    Tagesgericht.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 370 + insets.top,
                 size.width + 90, size.height + 50);
    size = Salate.getPreferredSize();
    Aktionsangebot.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 450 + insets.top,
                 size.width + 103, size.height + 50);
    size = Salate.getPreferredSize();
    Getränke.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 530 + insets.top,
                 size.width + 103, size.height + 50);


    } 

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("AbsoluteLayoutDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     


    //Set up the content pane.
    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    //Size and display the window.
    Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
    frame.setSize(1200 + insets.left + insets.right,
                  900 + insets.top + insets.bottom);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    }); 
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JPanel so you will have location to present your image.

```
JImageComponent myImage = new JImageComponent(insertYourImageHere);

imagePanel.add(myImage);
```

You can also use a JLabel to store the image.

```
frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Path to your image")));
```

Comment: I need JPanel libary for that i guess.
Where to put it? And do i need to add something so JImageComponent works?

Comment: @Jennifer96 you can just `import javax.swing.*;`

Comment: Thanks for the answers but somehow i cant get it working. :(

Comment: @Jennifer96 you need to more specific about whats not working, is there an error? if there is whats the error? if it is a case you are not being able to do what you want to do i suggest you follow some online tutorial.

Comment: I solved my problem with this:

                JLabel jl = new JLabel();
                jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Tom\\Desktop\\logo.jpg"));
                panel.add(jl);
                frame.add(panel);

But i still wanna understand your way of doing it. Can you help me?

Comment: There are many different ways of doing this, again i suggest an online tutorial to learn the basics. since you are learning it fresh it doesn't matter if you use the most efficient way or not at this stage. If you have specific issue you can create a question but please read the guide lines for how to post questions.